# iPad Application Distribution

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have create an iPad application for enterprise distribution and its working very well but I want to change the message that appear when application start installing on the iPad from waiting to loading or something like that, how I can do that?

And what is the full list of variable I can use it with Manifest file (.pList)?

Comment: I'm rather confused as to what you are asking.  Perhaps you could clarify a bit more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may not change the "Waiting" and "Installing" text. It has nothing to do with your application, but with iOS.